# WebView using loadDataWithBaseURL and loadUrl interchangeably

Tags: javascript, android, interface

I am experimenting the communication feasibility of Java and JavaScript in Android..

1. Load the page:

   ```
   webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(base_url, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
   ```
2. When the page finished loading, call JavaScript:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
   {
       webview.loadUrl("javascript:doSomething()");
   }
   ```
3. The JavaScript has a callback interface, then reload the page:

   ```
   @JavascriptInterface
   public void onJavaScriptExecuted()
   {
       webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(base_url, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
   }
   ```

After step 3, I expected the `onPageFinished()` to be called again, but it does not..

What is wrong with the 2nd call to `loadDataWithBaseURL()`?

Comment: Does the onJavaScriptExecuted() actually get called?

Comment: @theswine it certainly did get called or my question would have changed to "why it doesn't get called". This is an old post and I have long abandoned using WebView. However, any solution to this is welcome as it might benefits others who have the same issue. =)

Comment: I was trying similar stuff recently and my problem was that `webview.loadUrl()` did not see the context of the javascript in a page loaded using `loadDataWithBaseURL` - if I did what you do, I would get "undefined `doSomething()`" exception in step 2. I had to inject code to the page's event handlers to interact with it. Those functions are kind of tricky (`loadData` and `loadDataWithBaseURL` have completely different implementations) and I suppose they changed behavior over Android versions.

Comment: @theswine from what I can remember, the exception you mentioned will take place when you have a base_url that points away from the target location, perhaps you can look into this. `loadData and `loadDataWithBaseURL are differ by pure base_url on my mind. Whatever it is, have to get yourself familiarize with WebKit all those stuff if WebView is your only solution. =(